# Divide an array's element by 2 for k times such that array's sum is minimized

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, data-structures

I have an array of n integers and I need to divide any of it's elements by 2 (return the ceiling of the result) for k times such that the sum is minimum. The value of k can be very large as compared to n.

I am using this code:

```
    private static int GetMaxSum(int[] array, int k)
    {
        int n = array.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            var indexAtMax = GetMaxIndex(array);
            if (array[indexAtMax] == 1) break;
            array[indexAtMax] = array[indexAtMax] / 2 + array[indexAtMax] % 2;
        }
        return array.Sum();
    }

    private static int GetMaxIndex(int[] array)
    {
        int maxIndex = 0;
        int max = array[0];
        for  (int i=1; i<array.Length;i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > max)
            {
                max = array[i];
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
```

How can we improve the performance further probably by using max heap or some other data structure?

Comment: Which problem do you have with current code?

Comment: Your idea of using a max heap sounds good why not do this and ask again if you have troubles implementing a max heap

Comment: This seems like a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ackdari I don't how to do it in C#. Any suggestion to improve performance further using C#.

Comment: @itsme86 code review does not provide performance improvement.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski No problems just want to improve the complexity further. It's just a DS & algorithm question.

Comment: Code Review absolutely can help with performance.  See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it says "If you have a **working piece of code** from your project and are looking for **open-ended feedback** in ... Performance … then you are in the right place!"  Seeking feedback about performance for a working piece of code sounds like a pretty good description of this question.  Note that both sites have a [tag:Performance] tag that would be appropriate, too.

Comment: With a max-heap, complexity will be O(n+ k logn)

Comment: @Damien I am trying to understand it but if you cah help with an answer, it would be of great help.

Comment: Creating a max-heap is O(n), taking the max of it is O(1), inserting a new element is O(log n). I have writtent a simple C++ code for it, but i don't know C#, sorry. C++ has the useful make_heap() function, I don't know if there is something eqivalent in C#

Comment: @Damien Can we also modify the max and what is the complexity of the recalculation of max.

Comment: After insertion of a new element at the back (O(1)), reordering of the heap should be O(log n). Note that I did not implement max-heap myself, I just use the corresponding C++ functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the assumption was that k>>n, the simpler algorithms are of the order O(kn) which can be too much of iterations. 
I have written this code thinking of the problem and how can I limit sorting or calculating min/max. I have divided the array into subarrays so that the operations can be performed on subarrays without thinking of the order of operations.

```
    private static int GetMinSum(int[] array, int k)
    {
        int n = array.Length;
        var sum = 0;
        k = GetOptimizedListAndK(array, n, k, out var lists);

        //If more sublists are needed  
        if (k > 0)
        {
            var count = lists.CountSum;
            var key = lists.Key;
            if (key > 0)
            {
                var poweroftwo = 1 << key;
                sum += count * poweroftwo - k * poweroftwo / 2;
                var dictionary2 = GetDictionary(array, lists, poweroftwo);
                key = dictionary2.Keys.Last();

                while (k > 0 && key > 0)
                {

                    var list2 = dictionary2[key];
                    count = list2.Count;
                    if (k >= count)
                    {
                        list2.ForEach(
                             index => array[index] = array[index] / 2 + array[index] % 2);


                        dictionary2.Remove(key);

                        key = dictionary2.Keys.LastOrDefault();

                        k -= count;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (k <= Log2(count))
                        {

                            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                            {

                                var indexAtMax = GetMaxIndex(list2, array);
                                array[indexAtMax] = array[indexAtMax] / 2 + array[indexAtMax] % 2;
                            }
                            k = 0;
                        }
                        if (count - k <= Log2(count))
                        {
                            var minIndexes = GetMinIndexes(list2, array, count - k);

                            foreach (var i in list2)
                            {
                                if (!minIndexes.Contains(i))
                                {
                                    array[i] = array[i] / 2 + array[i] % 2;
                                }
                            }

                            k = 0;
                        }
                        if (k > 0)
                        {
                            poweroftwo = 1 << key;
                            sum += list2.Count * poweroftwo - k * poweroftwo / 2;
                            dictionary2 = GetDictionary(array, list2, poweroftwo);
                            key = dictionary2.Keys.Last();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return array.Sum() + sum;
    }
    private static int GetOptimizedListAndK(int[] array, int n, int k, out Lists lists)
    {
        lists = null;
        Dictionary<int, Lists> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Lists>();
        PopulatePowerBasedDictionary(array, n, dictionary);
        var key = dictionary.Keys.Max();
        while (key > 0 && k > 0)
        {
           lists = dictionary[key];
           var count = lists.CountSum;

            if (k >= count)
            {
                lists.ForEach(list => list.ForEach(index => array[index] = array[index] / 2 + array[index] % 2));
                if (key > 1)
                {
                    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key - 1, out var lowerlists))
                    {
                        lowerlists.AddRange(lists);
                        lowerlists.CountSum += count;
                    }
                    else dictionary.Add((key - 1), lists);
                }

                dictionary.Remove(key);

                key--;

                k -= count;
            }
            else
            {
                if (k < Log2(count))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                    {
                        var indexAtMax = GetMaxIndex(lists, array);
                        array[indexAtMax] = array[indexAtMax] / 2 + array[indexAtMax] % 2;
                    }
                    k = 0;
                }
                if (count - k < Log2(count))
                {
                    var minIndexes = GetMinIndexes(lists, array, count - k);
                    foreach (var list in lists)
                    {
                        foreach (var i in list)
                        {
                            if (!minIndexes.Contains(i))
                            {
                                array[i] = array[i] / 2 + array[i] % 2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    k = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return k;
    }

    private static void PopulatePowerBasedDictionary(int[] array, int n, Dictionary<int, Lists> dictionary)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] < 2) continue;
            var log2 = Log2(array[i]);
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(log2, out var lists))
            {
                lists[0].Add(i);
                lists.CountSum++;
            }
            else
            {
                lists = new Lists(1,log2) { new List<int> { i } };
                dictionary.Add(log2, lists);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int GetMaxIndex(List<int> list, int[] array)
    {
        var maxIndex = 0;
        var max = 0;

        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            if (array[i] > max)
            {
                maxIndex = i;
                max = array[i];
            }
        }

        return maxIndex;
    }

    private static SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> GetDictionary(int[] array, Lists lists, int poweroftwo)
    {
        SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, List<int>>();


        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                array[i] = array[i] - poweroftwo;
                if (array[i] < 2)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var log2 = Log2(array[i]);
                if (dictionary.TryGetValue(log2, out var list2))
                {
                    list2.Add(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    list2 = new List<int> { i };
                    dictionary.Add(log2, list2);
                }

            }
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
    private static SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> GetDictionary(int[] array, List<int> list, int poweroftwo)
    {
        SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, List<int>>();

        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            array[i] = array[i] - poweroftwo;
            if (array[i] < 2)
            {
                continue;
            }
            var log2 = Log2(array[i]);
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(log2, out var list2))
            {
                list2.Add(i);
            }
            else
            {
                list2 = new List<int> { i };
                dictionary.Add(log2, list2);
            }


        }

        return dictionary;
    }
    private static int GetMaxIndex(Lists lists, int[] array)
    {
        var maxIndex = 0;
        var max = 0;
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                if (array[i]>max)
                {
                    maxIndex = i;
                    max = array[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
    private static HashSet<int> GetMinIndexes(Lists lists, int[] array, int k)
    {
        var mins = new HashSet<int>();
        var minIndex = 0;
        var min = int.MaxValue;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            foreach (var list in lists)
            {
                foreach (var i in list)
                {
                    if (array[i] < min && !mins.Contains(i))
                    {
                        minIndex = i;
                        min = array[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            mins.Add(minIndex);
            min = int.MaxValue;
        }

        return mins;
    }
    private static HashSet<int> GetMinIndexes(List<int> list, int[] array, int k)
    {
        var mins = new HashSet<int>();
        var minIndex = 0;
        var min = int.MaxValue;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {

                foreach (var i in list)
                {
                    if (array[i] < min && !mins.Contains(i))
                    {
                        minIndex = i;
                        min = array[i];
                    }
                }
            mins.Add(minIndex);
            min = int.MaxValue;
        }

        return mins;
    }
    private static int Log2(int n)
    {
        return BitOperations.Log2((uint)n);
    }
```

Lists Class:

```
public class Lists:List<List<int>>
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public int CountSum { get; set; }

    public Lists(int countSum, int key):base()
    {
        CountSum = countSum;
        Key = key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your requirements, your solution seens way too complicated (and apparently wrong according to comments).

I can't really think this through right now, but wouldn't it be the case that the global solution is made up of optimal intermediate steps? The order in which you divide is irrelevant and the problem is linear.

If that is the case, you simply have to evaluate the optimal division in each step and that is not very hard to do:

```
static void Minimize(int[] arr, int k)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        var maxGainIndex = -1;
        var maxGain = int.MinValue;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            var gain = arr[i] - (arr[i]/2 + arr[i] % 2);

            if (gain > maxGain)
            {
                maxGain = gain;
                maxGainIndex = i;
            }

        }

        arr[maxGainIndex] -= maxGain;
    }
}
```

If I'm not wrong, the asymptotic behavior of this algorithm is O(k·n).

**UPDATE:**
Based on claims of posted code being far less optimal, I've taken the liberty of benchmarking both algorithms with these results on my machine:

```
 Input array: 100;120;80;55;75;115;125;150;90;35;65;77;89;10;11;113;200;300
 Number of divisions: 20
 Running benchmarks in Release mode without debugger attached.

1000000 of GetMimimum finished in 584 ms with result 704.
1000000 of GetMimimum2 finished in 8846 ms with result 704.
```

Benchmarking code can be found here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ITx53q
The performance gain of my proposed algorithm is rather staggering (x15), which was expected because your solution is, as evaluated initally, overcomplicated at best for such a simple problem.

Comment: @DeepakMishra lol, have you even tried to benchmark both solutions? Mine is like 10 to 15 times faster on average on my machine and 4-5 times in NET Fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/XkADtx) which is not a valid benchmark environment but a way to show you the benchmarking code. Smart linq solution that you have to stare at hard to understand what it does, because its far from obvious at first or second glance, and is on top of that slower than a very simple algorithm is far from optimal in my book, but whatever rows your boat.

Comment: @DeepakMishra I’m not sure what you are talking about. Your solution starts with a loop from `0` to `k`, so I’m finding it hard to understand how you are avoiding the issue of `k` being orders bigger than `n`. Do explain, please. Your algorithm is O(k•whatever).

Comment: I'd wager that the `if (array[indexAtMax] == 1) break;` conditional is what's causing the original algorithm to outperform yours, @InBetween. Once the largest item can't be divided any further, it just breaks out and saves iterations. Especially in the example given (here)[dotnetfiddle.net/6lepcO] where the array is filled with 1 and so there is only one iteration of the outer `for` loop. A similar optimization, such as maybe checking `maxGain == 0` and breaking will probably change the results.

Comment: @joshuarobinson that benchmark is flawed. If the initial array is all ones, the algorithm is pointless, it’s a noop. Granted that the optimization you are proposing will improve the performance but that is a totally data driven decision. If the algorithm is hitting ones frequently then it should be evaluated to see if the mean output improves or not. With a reasonable starting array (granted I’m not hitting ones) the performance of my algorithm is 10-15 times faster on my machine.

Comment: @InBetween You just tried to improve the performance of the linq part which did not worked as expected. Overall you didn't provide any improvement at complexity level. Even with the reasonable starting array your algorithm is slower dotnetfiddle.net/TL5Il2  and with that array if  you set k>>n, your algorithm would be very very slow,